# groupby and find the first non-zero value

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have the following df, the last column is the desired output. thanks!

```
group  date  value    desired_first_nonzero

  1    jan2019    0        2                      
  1    jan2019    2        2
  1    feb2019    3        2
  1    mar2019    4        2
  1    mar2019    5        2
  2    feb2019    0        4
  2    feb2019    0        4
  2    mar2019    0        4
  2    mar2019    4        4
  2    apr2019    5        4
```

I want to group by "group" and find the first non-zero value

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`GroupBy.transform`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.transform.html) with a custom function to get the index of the first non-zero value with [`idxmax`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.idxmax.html) (that return the **first** `True` value here):

```
df['desired_first_nonzero'] = (df.groupby('group')['value']
                                 .transform(lambda s: s[s.ne(0).idxmax()])
                              )
```

alternatively, using an intermediate Series:

```
s = df.set_index('group')['value']
df['desired_first_nonzero'] = df['group'].map(s[s.ne(0)].groupby(level=0).first())
```

output:

```
   group     date  value  desired_first_nonzero
0      1  jan2019      0                      2
1      1  jan2019      2                      2
2      1  feb2019      3                      2
3      1  mar2019      4                      2
4      1  mar2019      5                      2
5      2  feb2019      0                      4
6      2  feb2019      0                      4
7      2  mar2019      0                      4
8      2  mar2019      4                      4
9      2  apr2019      5                      4
```

Comment: Is it possible to filter first then aggregate? Might be faster maybe

Comment: @sammywemmy yes, I was thinking about that too, see update ;)

Answer (score 1):

This should do the job:

```
# the given example
d = {'group': [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2], 'value': [0, 2, 3, 4, 5, 0, 0, 0, 4, 5]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)

first_non_zero = pd.DataFrame(df[df['value'] != 0].groupby('group').head(1))
print(first_non_zero)
```

Output:

```
    group   value
1   1   2
8   2   4
```

Then you can distributed as needed for each group row.